# execl with arbitrary argument zero

Tags: python, arguments, exec

If in Python 3 I do ...

```
import os
# ...
os.execl("abc", ["zebra", "alpha", "beta"])
```

... then program `abc` sees the arguments as `'abc'` (the program name), `'alpha'`, and `'beta'`.

How do I make program `abc` see the arguments as `'zebra'` (an arbitrary substitute program name), `'alpha'`, and `'beta'`?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a dummy item at the beginning of the list?

Comment: Why do you not use the `subprocess` module?

Comment: Inserting a dummy argument at the beginning of the list shifts everything else down. And I can't sue the subprocess module without forking. I don't want to fork. I want to exec directly.

Comment: No. I want the destination program "abc" to see as sys.argv: ["zebra", "alpha", "beta"].